# How to get the default material design look and feel for paper elements in the starter kit

Tags: material-design, polymer-1.0

I started a new Polymer application using `polymer-cli` and the polymer starter kit template.When I try to add an element from the paper element, I didn't get the look and feel in the documentation. For example, in the following code, I expected to get a lifted element but this didn't happen

```
    <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <div>
      <paper-material elevation=1>

      This should have elevation

      </paper-material>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you install the paper-element via bower and import it?

Comment: Nope. I think I just installed paper-material. Is it necessary ?

Comment: Yes. You need to import the element to be able to use it. Using a `link` tag. like this: `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">` You will need to make sure the path is correct.

Comment: In fact, I do have paper-material imported but the style is not as I expected. I need to specify the style in order to get the lifted blank paper look paper-material {
        display: inline-block;
        background: white;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 8px;
        padding: 16px;
        border-radius: 2px;
      }